# What wildcard character in xpressive means the entire end of text?

Tags: regex, boost-xpressive

With ANSI C PCRE I could extract sections and their content by means of:

```
(?ms)^\\[(.+?)\\](.*?)(?=\\n\\[|.\\z)
```

From `[sec1] a = b [sec2] c = d`
 I got `[sec1] a = b` and `[sec2] c = d`

But how i can do it in xpressive?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the "dynamic" dialect, you can use exactly the same syntax as for PCRE. For example (untested):

```
using namespace boost::xpressive;
sregex rx = sregex::compile("(?ms)^\\[(.+?)\\](.*?)(?=\\n\\[|.\\z");
```

If you're using the "static" dialect of xpressive, the wildcard pattern is `_` (in namespace `boost::xpressive`. It matches any character. If you want to match any character except a newline character, you can use `~_n`. Finally, if you want to match any single character except a logical newline (`\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`, and Unicode variants), you can use `~_ln`.

(Edit: fixed typo)